# WDS server & Cisco ASA (DHCP)

Tags: dhcp, cisco-asa, pxe-boot, wds

My setup:

WDS server (w2indows 2003 R2) located on subnet 10.1.1.10 
Various site locations all on different subnets. Eah site has a Cisco ASA firewall configured to respdon to DHCP requests.

Questions

Is it possible to leave my Cisco ASA's as the DHCP servers, but still somewhow forward PXE requests over to the WDS server without manually setting option 66 & 67 on my ASA. I want to keep my WDS server as the central server for all PXE configurations ( in case I change the boot file in feature etc...)

So in essence I want:

1. Cisco ASA to providce IP addresses
2. Cisco ASA to forward PXE request to 10.1.1.0 subnet so WDS server can responds
3. WDS server to respond to PXE request
4. All PXE configuration to stay on WDS server

Many thanks

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible, as the DHCP service on the ASAs is not terribly flexible.

Comment: Have you considered centralising the DHCP and just using a DHCP relay from each ASA?

Comment: thanks that makes sense Shane, as I could not find the option. In the end I installed a local DHCP server at one site and moved the WDS server to my lcoal subnet